# Input system reference trouble

Tags: c++, reference, sfml

I'm using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) for input system in my application.

```
size_t WindowHandle;
WindowHandle = ...; // Here I get the handler

sf::Window InputWindow(WindowHandle);
const sf::Input *InputHandle = &InputWindow.GetInput();  // [x] Error
```

At the last lines I have to get reference for the input system.

Here is declaration of **GetInput** from [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Window.htm#49db47a79ca98b7d65087adeea06e919):

```
const Input & sf::Window::GetInput () const
```

The problem is:

```
>invalid conversion from ‘const sf::Input*’ to ‘sf::Input*’
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a special reason why you want to have a pointer rather than a reference? 
If not, you could try this:

```
const sf::Input & InputHandle = InputWindow.GetInput();
```

This will return you a reference to your Input handle.

Btw, this worked for me:

```
const int& test(int& i)
{
  return i;  
}

int main()
{
   int i = 4;

   const int* j = &test(i);

   cout << *j << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output : 4

Don't know why your compiler doesn't want you to point the reference.